# How to calculate the sum of multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am trying to solve an equation where I add numbers from a list of arrays following the indices.

Each array of a list are a randomly generated fixed-length array of 4 numbers like so:

```
const list = [
  [2, 9, 1, 2],
  [2, 3, 9, 4],
  [4, 7, 8, 1]
]
```

So what I am trying to do is get the sum of each number of each index from each array. Like so:

```
const list = [
  [2, 9, 1, 2],
  [2, 3, 9, 4],
  [4, 7, 8, 1]
]

// expectedResult = [8, 19, 18, 7];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is another approach that uses [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the first array, nested with a [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that generated the total of the corresponding column.

```js
const list = [
  [2, 9, 1, 2],
  [2, 3, 9, 4],
  [4, 7, 8, 1]
];

const sums = list[0].map((x, idx) => list.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr[idx], 0));

console.log(sums);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Now this one is nice

Answer (score 5):

```js
const list = [
  [2, 9, 1, 2],
  [2, 3, 9, 4],
  [4, 7, 8, 1],
];

const result = list.reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => c + b[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Update: an explanation was **asked** for.

First of all **reduce** will given an array (of arrays) and want to *reduce* it down to single value (an array).  To do this it will call the first arrow function 2 times.  The first time **a** will be **[2,9,1,2]** and **b** will be **[2,3,9,4]**.  With **a** and **b** the first arrow function will return a **map** of **a**.  With **a** being an array it will return an array where each element is added to the corresponding element of array **b**.  The result of this first map will be **[4,12,10,6]**.  **reduce** will now call the first arrow function a second time with **a** (the first map result) **[4,12,10,6]** and **b** (the final array element of the input **[4,7,8,1]**).  This arrow function will do the same thing as before: returning an array where each **a** element is added to the corresponding element of **b**.  **map** will return **[8,19,18,7]**.  Since there are no more input elements **reduce** will return that value (the array).

Comment: I personally think this is the most straightforward answer. Though a little explanation to OP would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option using two loops with forEach

```js
const blockList = [[2, 9, 1, 2], [2, 3, 9, 4], [4, 7, 8, 1]];
const result = [];

blockList.forEach((v, index) =>
  v.forEach((val, i) => {
    result[i] = result[i] ? result[i] : 0;
    result[i] += val;
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yZRrKy?editors=1010

Comment: You can initialise the result array with default value like `const result = [0, 0, 0, 0]`, so you don't have to check `result[i] = result[i] ? result[i] : 0` on every iteration.

Comment: @YongQuan, if each array length other than 4 , then it will be issue of getting NaN

Comment: the solution which i have provided works for all array lengths

Comment: true, my comment is based on OP's spec that each array length is fixed at 4 and each value is valid number.

Comment: @YongQuan, if length is fixed and know before , then yes as you said we can set result array with default value :)

Comment: You can initialise the result as `= new Array(length).fill(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Here we create an array with index we add particular element to particular index. and than just take the values out from object.

```js
const list = [[2, 9, 1, 2],[2, 3, 9, 4],[4, 7, 8, 1]]

let op = list.reduce((op,inp)=>{
   inp.forEach((e,i)=>op[i] = op[i] ? op[i]+e : e)
   return op
},[])

console.log(op)
```

Comment: why init with `{}`? Why not just `[]`?

Comment: @YongQuan oh you're right :).  in this case `[]` is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Use nested loops:

```js
const blocklist = [[2,9,1,2], [2,3,9,4], [4,7,8,1]], calculatedBlocks = [];
for (let j = 0, sum = 0; j < blocklist[0].length; j++, sum = 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < blocklist.length; i++) sum += blocklist[i][j];
  calculatedBlocks.push(sum);
}

console.log(calculatedBlocks);
```

Comment: I think the down-votes are related to the first version of your answer, it was giving a different result that the expected one. However, now that you fixed it, I give you my support.

Comment: True, could be.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.reduce` in combination with an iterative `for...of` loop that pulls out the index and value of each inner array using v.entries. Then simply assign them by index to the accumulator Array and add them together.

```
let expectedResult = list.reduce((a,v) => {
 for(let [i, n] of v.entries()) a[i] = (a[i] || 0) + n
 return a;
}, []);
```

```js
const list = [
  [2, 9, 1, 2],
  [2, 3, 9, 4],
  [4, 7, 8, 1]
]

let expectedResult = list.reduce((a,v) => {
 for(let [i, n] of v.entries()) a[i] = (a[i] || 0) + n
 return a;
}, []);

console.log(expectedResult);
```