# Combine multiple arrays and add their values

Tags: javascript

I have (5) arrays. I'm trying to combine the (5) arrays into one array and then sum all the values together. I know with (2) arrays you can use the concat method but what about when you have (5) arrays?

```js
const numArr = [132, 233, 5002, 3232, 3220];
const numArr2 = [123, 212, 535, 20, 2492];
const numArr3 = [90, 21, 32, 200, 71];
const numArr4 = [90, 16, 2, 200110, 12];
const numArr5 = [90, 21, 76, 240, 132];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the sum of multiple arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712774/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-multiple-arrays)

Comment: Not really. The link to the question you provided doesn't include spread operator in the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more than (2) arrays that you wish to combine you can use the spread operator. This will allow you to take the array values from the (5) arrays and push it into a new array.

Once you have all the values you can use the reduce method to sum the numbers.

```js
const numArr = [132, 233, 5002, 3232, 3220];
const numArr2 = [123, 212, 535, 20, 2492];
const numArr3 = [90, 21, 32, 20000, 1];
const numArr4 = [90, 16, 2, 200110, 12];
const numArr5 = [90, 21, 76, 240, 132];

let mainArr = [];

arr = [...numArr, ...numArr2, ...numArr3, ...numArr4, ...numArr5];

mainArr.push(arr);

const addArrValues = (acc, value) => acc + value;
let finalValue = arr.reduce(addArrValues);
console.log('Sum is:', finalValue);
```

Comment: Here is documentation in case you want to learn about spread and reduce:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 3):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to concatenate the arrays;

```js
const numArr = [132, 233, 5002, 3232, 3220];
const numArr2 = [123, 212, 535, 20, 2492];
const numArr3 = [90, 21, 32, 200, 71];
const numArr4 = [90, 16, 2, 200110, 12];
const numArr5 = [90, 21, 76, 240, 132];

const concatenated = [...numArr, ...numArr2, ...numArr3, ...numArr4, ...numArr5];
console.log(concatenated);
```

To sum the values, you can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const numArr = [132, 233, 5002, 3232, 3220];
const numArr2 = [123, 212, 535, 20, 2492];
const numArr3 = [90, 21, 32, 200, 71];
const numArr4 = [90, 16, 2, 200110, 12];
const numArr5 = [90, 21, 76, 240, 132];

const concatenated = [...numArr, ...numArr2, ...numArr3, ...numArr4, ...numArr5];
const sum = concatenated.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
console.log(concatenated);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

> I know with (2) arrays you can use the **concat** method but **what about when you have (5) arrays**?

You can add another 3 arrays to `concat()`.

```js
const numArr = [132, 233, 5002, 3232, 3220];
const numArr2 = [123, 212, 535, 20, 2492];
const numArr3 = [90, 21, 32, 200, 71];
const numArr4 = [90, 16, 2, 200110, 12];
const numArr5 = [90, 21, 76, 240, 132];

console.log(
  numArr.concat(numArr2, numArr3, numArr4, numArr5)
);
```

> The concat() method is used to merge two **or more arrays**
>
> Source: [Array.prototype.concat() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Sum of array is already well described in another SO Answers like [How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator to merge the arrays and then apply a `reduce` to sum all the elements:

```js
const numArr = [132, 233, 5002, 3232, 3220];
const numArr2 = [123, 212, 535, 20, 2492];
const numArr3 = [90, 21, 32, 200, 71];
const numArr4 = [90, 16, 2, 200110, 12];
const numArr5 = [90, 21, 76, 240, 132];

const sum = [ ...numArr, ...numArr2, ...numArr3, ...numArr4, ...numArr5 ]
    .reduce((a, x) => a + x, 0)
```

But possibly the better idea (in terms of performance due to allocation of temporary arrays) would be to sum all the arrays first and then sum the sums:

```js
const sum = [ numArr, numArr2, numArr3, numArr4, numArr5 ]
    .map(x => x.reduce((a, x) => a + x, 0))
    .reduce((a, x) => a + x, 0)
```